# Echo the names of all cookies

Tags: php

I'm using this code to display a list of the names of all cookies (not values):

```
foreach ($cookies as $key=>$item){
    if (is_numeric($key)) {
        echo "$key,";
    }
}
```

That is working correctly.  But, I'm trying to assign the full results to a variable that can be used later on in my code.  I just need it to be a list of the cookie names, separated by a comma.

I tried turning it into a function and assigning it to a variable like this:

```
$cookies = $_COOKIE;
function get_cookies() {
    foreach ($cookies as $key=>$item){
        if (is_numeric($key)) {
            return "$key,";
        }
    }
}

$all_cookies = get_cookies();

echo $all_cookies;
```

But when I do that, I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$cookies` is defined outside the function so the function doesn't know about it. Pass it as a parameter or just use `$_COOKIES` (*not* `$_COOKIE`) in the function.

Comment: `function get_cookies($cookies)`

Comment: You want "all" cookies or the first numeric indexed one?

Comment: If you wanted *all* of the cookies names wouldn't `array_keys()` be a better choice?

Comment: echo implode(',' array_keys($cookies) );